# Keep Emacs from scrolling past end of buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp, customization

Is there anything I can add to my .emacs file to keep emacs from adding new lines when I scroll past the end of the buffer with my mouse or the scrollbar? I already have

```
(setq next-line-add-newlines nil)
```

but that seems to only be applying to when I am moving with the keyboard. I've done quite a few searches on the subject to no avail.

Any tips are greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I see End of Buffer message when I do scroll with mouse or scroll-bar up on reaching the last line in the buffer.  Which version of Emacs do you have and on what OS?  I have GNU Emacs 23.2 on Debian machine.

Comment: I'm using GNU Emacs 23.2 on Mac OSX 10.6. I noticed that it is now doing it for some files and not for others. Is it maybe because it works in certian modes and not others?

Comment: Does your cursor move when you scroll? Or does it move only when it reaches the top/bottom of the window?

Answer (score 3):

Check the value of the the variable `next-line-add-newlines` in the buffers/modes that it's misbehaving.  You can do so by: <kbd>C-h v next-line-add-newlines</kbd> (or <kbd>M-x describe-variable</kbd>).

It could be something in the major/minor mode that's enabling it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked whether this also happens in standard emacs (i.e. have you tested this behaviour when running emacs with `--no-init-file`) ?

If it doesn't, then the cause for this problem has to lie somewhere in your dotfiles.