# How to prevent Emacs from scrolling with the mouse past the end of the buffer?

Tags: emacs, vertical-scrolling

The default behavior is that Emacs keeps scrolling the last line to the center of the frame. How can I keep the last line at the bottom of the frame when I scroll using the mouse?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep Emacs from scrolling past end of buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675772/keep-emacs-from-scrolling-past-end-of-buffer)

Answer (score 1):

```lisp
(setq scroll-conservatively 101)
```

Here is the information from the `*Help*` window produced by `describe-variable`:

```
scroll-conservatively is a variable defined in `C source code'.
Its value is 101
Original value was 0

Documentation:
Scroll up to this many lines, to bring point back on screen.
If point moves off-screen, redisplay will scroll by up to
‘scroll-conservatively’ lines in order to bring point just barely
onto the screen again.  If that cannot be done, then redisplay
recenters point as usual.

If the value is greater than 100, redisplay will never recenter point,
but will always scroll just enough text to bring point into view, even
if you move far away.

A value of zero means always recenter point if it moves off screen.

You can customize this variable.
```

Comment: Try with `emacs -q`.  Most people copy a bunch of stuff from the internet dealing with `scroll-step` and they set `scroll-conservatively` to a zillion trillion billion, but none of that is necessary.  This one line is all that is needed with no user-configuration.  `(setq scroll-conservatively 101)`  Once you verify that it works with `emacs -q`, then you can track down the conflict in your user-configuration.  No need for anything like `scroll-up-aggressively` or `scroll-down-aggressively` or `auto-window-vscroll`; no need to play around with the `scroll-margin` -- none of that stuff.

Comment: I use emacs for mac os x and scroll with the mouse.

Comment: Me too. Try with `emacs -q` -- i.e., try with no user-configuration -- just use that one line of `(setq scroll-conservatively 101)` and see what happens.  You may also wish to add:  `(setq mouse-wheel-scroll-amount '(1 ((shift) . 1) ((control) . nil)))` so that the mouse wheel only scrolls one line at a time instead of the default of 5 lines at a time.

Comment: If you have evaluated `(setq scroll-conservatively 101)` after starting with `emacs -q` as indicated in the previous comment (e.g., `M-x eval-expression`), and still you do not have the desired result, then please consider spending some time to edit your question to provide everyone with a reproducible recipe and a better description of what it is exactly that you are experiencing.  Anyone reading this thread, should be able to start Emacs with no user configuration and duplicate the exact behavior you experience so that we can understand the issue and then suggest a potential solution.